# I want to force a justification to both sides after using \newline

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, indentation

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\noindent In year 1000 somebody wrote something\footnote{\emph{something}} because he
wanted to. Some thought he is clever, but some said no. Yet 100 years later
somebody\footnote{\emph{something}}\footnote{\emph{something}}\newline and somebody
else\footnote{\emph{something}} did something. It means that is something important.
\end{document}
```

That's example for that. I cannot have "and" at the end of the line, but after using `\newline` a former line looks ugly. Any solution?

Note that I cannot delete the `\noindent`, because it's required.

Comment: Would `\linebreak` work? And please, let us know what exactly you need it for, it's not something people _should_ do.

Comment: You almost should never require `\noindent` the choice of indentation style should be a document level setting not something that you need to override on each paragraph.

Comment: I just used \noindent on example. In particular work it is already set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\noindent In year 1000 somebody wrote something\footnote{\emph{something}} because he
wanted to. Some thought he is clever, but some said no. Yet 100 years later
somebody\footnote{\emph{something}}\footnote{\emph{something}} and~somebody 
else\footnote{\emph{something}} did something. It means that is something important.
\end{document}
```

Artificially make "and" part of the next word with a hard space `~`.  It will prevent the line break after the word "and".

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a `\newline`, you can adjust the breaking penalty.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\noindent In year 1000 somebody wrote
something\footnote{\emph{something}} because he wanted to. Some
thought he is clever, but some said no. Yet 100 years later
somebody\footnote{\emph{something}}\footnote{\emph{something}}\penalty0
and somebody else\footnote{\emph{something}} did something. It means
that is something important.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\linebreak[0]` is to be preferred.

Comment: That's a bit dangerous as if the text is edited so the linebreak does not fall at the penalty you get no word space after the footnote mark (as you used an undelimited number so the newline in the source is gobbled looking for the end of the penalty)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- good point; it should be `\penalty0\relax ` I suppose, but I prefer Steven's solution in any case.